# How to simplify the following expression $X(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I try to simplify a matrix equation, but I'm confused about what I am doing.

It is crucial to take the dimensions of $X$ into acount, which are ($n$x$k$) with $n$ = number of observations (rows) and $k$ = parameters (columns)

I would solve it like this

$X(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}$

$X(X^{-1}(X^{T})^{-1})X^{T}$

$I I$

$I$

But being more critical I doubt my approach. My initial goal was to check the dimensions of the final $I$. Wheter it is $I_n$ or $I_k$

**Problem I**

I applied the rule $AA^{-1} = I$, I don't know whether this law always holds or only when the matrix is square. When I applied this rule on my problem, on the part $XX^{-1}$, I have a multiplication with the dimensions (n x k)(n x k), which seems not possible. Futhermore, by simplifying the inverse within the brackets I get $X^{-1}$, which is not possible, since $X$ is not square.

**Problem 2**

My second attempt was by first evaluating $(X^{T}X)^{-1}$, since the dimensions match (n x k)(k x n), which result in a square matrix and is therefore invertible. But now I cannot apply the $AA^{-1} = I$ rule anymore, which inhibits me from finally obtaining a matrix $I$.

**Question**

I hope I made my confusion clear. My questions are:

1. What is the feedback on the problems I came across?
2. What are the dimensions of the final $I$ matrix and why?

**Extra**

The derivation I try to verify

\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{E}\left(e^{\prime} e\right) & =\mathbf{E}\left(\operatorname{trace}\left(e^{\prime} e\right)\right)=\mathbf{E}\left(\operatorname{trace}\left(e e^{\prime}\right)\right)=\operatorname{trace}\left(\mathbf{E}\left(e e^{\prime}\right)\right) \\
& =\operatorname{trace}\left(\sigma^2 M\right)=\sigma^2 \operatorname{trace}\left(I_n-X\left(X^{\prime} X\right)^{-1} X^{\prime}\right) \\
& =\sigma^2 \operatorname{trace}\left(I_n\right)-\sigma^2 \operatorname{trace}\left(X\left(X^{\prime} X\right)^{-1} X^{\prime}\right) \\
& =\sigma^2 \operatorname{trace}\left(I_n\right)-\sigma^2 \operatorname{trace}\left(\left(X^{\prime} X\right)^{-1} X^{\prime} X\right) \\
& =\sigma^2 \operatorname{trace}\left(I_n\right)-\sigma^2 \operatorname{trace}\left(I_k\right) \\
& =\sigma^2(n-k)
\end{aligned}

Comment: there is no equation.

Comment: thanks for pointing out. I edited my question

Comment: Without further assumptions you can't simplify this. $H=X(X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top$ is the famous *hat* matrix from linear regressions, see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix)

Comment: Yes! I am currenly learning multiple regression. I edited my post to show the derivation I try to verify. Could you explain which assumptions are needed to prove that I will get a $I_{k}$ matrix? @jlammy

Comment: Trace$(AB)=$trace$(BA)= \sum\sum(a_{ij}b_{ji})$.  That is how they move the $X$ from the left to the right near the end.

Comment: Could you elaborate how that simplifies the expression?